# Paypal Billing Agreement is not created only for products with Recurring Profile

Tags: checkout, paypal-express, billing, recurring

I am trying to setup my magento store to receive `Recurring Payments` with Magento built-in functionality for `Recurring Profiles` and `Billing Agreements`.

But here is the issue I am having - `Paypal Billing Agreements` are not created for products wit Recurring Profiles (not on Paypal side nor in our Magento store). Otherwise when Recurring Profile is disabled for specific product - they are created just fine.

The process is this: client checks the checkbox to signup for billing agreement in checkout section of our magento store. Then he is redirected to Paypal website where he signs billing agreement, but after he is back to our site and the order is placed - billing agreements are not created.

Another weird thing is that even if "Billing Agreements" are not created - the payments are still going through (in paypal sandbox mode). Not sure though if it happens all the time.

Can anyone suggest what could be wrong?

Do I need to enable anything special for Recurring Payments on Paypal side for Billing Agreements to be created? Or is it Magento that is doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In EE, there's a setting in System > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods > Paypal Express Checkout > Advanced Settings > Billing Agreement Signup, which you can set (looks like default may be 'Never'). Hope that helps...