# How to test magento native Paypal Express recurring profile and order creation in Magento 1?

Tags: paypal-express, recurring

I have setup paypal sandbox account in our staging instance.
Also have setup product to order as recurring profile. I am able to addtocart recurring product and complete checkout process with Paypal express payment method as recurring payment engine (magento native). The recurring profiles are being successfully creating in Admin section. However the recurring orders are not creating in Magento. On debugging could find that need to setup IPN url in Paypal sandbox account so that Paypal can call IPN url and update status in Magento.

However i couldn't find any settings to set IPN in Paypal Sandbox account.
I found IPN simulator tool in dashboard section but that also not useful to test recurring orders.

I need to test the complete recurring profile, recurring order creation workflow in Magento1 using paypal sandbox account.

Someone please help me.

Comment: hi anand this links will help you 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12391/paypal-billing-agreement-is-not-created-only-for-products-with-recurring-profile?rq=1

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92007/paypal-recurring-profile-related-orders-issue?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Just check once if IPN handler URL is like: http://SITE_BASE_URL/index.php/paypal/ipn/index/

**To set IPN URL:**

1. Log in to your Paypal account
2. Navigate to your Account's summary page. Scroll down and you should be able to see the "Seller Preferences".
3. In this page, find the "Instant Payment Notifications" option and click the "Update" button/link.
4. Click "Choose IPN Settings" to specify your listener's URL and activate the listener.
5. Specify the Default URL for your listener in the Notification URL field as

Notification URL: `http://SITE_BASE_URL/index.php/paypal/ipn/index/`

Comment: Thanks for reply Akhil.
For now my only concern to test Paypal recurring payment and order creation in staging instance with sandbox account. Then on Live.
How can i set ipn url for sandbox account to test recurring order creation in staging.

Comment: Answer updated.